# Run beta versions of sites SEO safely

Tags: seo, google-search, robots.txt

We have domain.com and want to test a new site template on beta.domain.com.

What is the correct way to run a beta test without affecting SEO of the main domain.com?

In the topic [SEO safe way to run beta of new site on seperate domain](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/82020/seo-safe-way-to-run-beta-of-new-site-on-seperate-domain) I found 2 recommendations:

1. Putting a robots.txt with noindex to our beta.domain.com
2. Canonicalizing beta.domain.com to domain.com *- Why? In any case we already have the noindex flag...*

Does it still actual in 2020? **Do you have any other recommendations?**

By the way, do we need to register beta.domain.com in Google Webmasters Tools?

Comment: Questions that are "is this still true in <year>" are not allowed. Instead, you are encouraged to offer a bounty to solicit new answers. You don't have any rep yet but getting it is easy. Answering a few questions will get you well on your way.

Answer (score 0):

No never register beta.domain.com on GSC as this will index the domain.

Sometimes robots ignore robots.txt and indexes sites

I personally put the nonindex in robots.txt and use 'Forcelogin' plugin (for WordPress websites) you can use HTTP auth for non WordPress dev websites.